# Button Linkedin JS API

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-jsapi

I have a problem with the Linkedin JS API. I would like to know how can I get the Linkedin register button without delaying (or not a really big one). Now it appears when the function onLinkedInLoad is executed but until that moment it does not appear. For that reason, it makes a little blink until the button is loaded and that is not really comfortable.

With another APIs like Google + or Facebook, is allowed to put the event "onClick" to any element and then execute any function from the API, but I haven't found how to do this on Linkedin JS API.

¿Does anybody know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I started working on LinkedIn JSAPI's recently myself and researched about the very same problem you're experiencing.
Turns out that's how LinkedIn's Login button is coded like that. I tried lots of CSS on it, and turns out you can't change its size. Also, its loading is always delayed.
When it finishes loading, it kind of disturbs the entire document.
To tackle that, may I suggest you try using some CSS like  `position:absolute` on it.